# Node.js install web3 issue

Tags: azure, npm, blockchain

when I want to install the web3 through powershell,
the system shown me this error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says
**`Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH`**

You can fix this by first installing Git for Windows as mentioned earlier https://git-for-windows.github.io/.

go to your Windows Start menu and open up Git CMD. Run the command there and it should work.